# Is it possible to obtain the current-voltage characteristic for a crystal using the Hartree–Fock (or DFT) calculation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, ab-initio-calculations, hartree-fock, electronic-transport, electric-field

In continuation of the question of [obtaining an electrical conductivity tensor (ECT) from the “first characteristics”](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9245/can-the-electrical-conductivity-tensor-of-a-crystal-be-obtained-from-a-hartree-f), will my following suggestion be correct? Since a crystal with an applied-to-it constant external electric field is known to be able to give a nonlinear current-voltage characteristic, then if a goal is to obtain ECT at different voltages applied to a crystal then this circumstance must be taken into account in the Hartree–Fock (or Kohn–Sham) equation such a way that an additional term defining a constant external electric field should be included into the equation.

Thus in order to obtain ECT for one single voltage applied to a crystal, there must be required one solution of the equation, for another voltage – another solution, and so on.

Comment: In others words, can the Kubo–Greenwood approach or Boltzmann Transport equation show nonlinearity (if any) of a crystal?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I just came here to ask if you've figured out the answer yet? Are you still working on this problem? Please update us!

Comment: I haven’t found a solution of this problem, and have postponed it. But it is still interested to me.

Comment: Thanks! What does "postponed" mean?

Comment: I mean I have set aside it for a time.

Comment: Thanks! The question can be reopened at any time by pinging me in a comment saying that it's no longer postponed or set aside!